# Set a theme and palette for all plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to simplify my plots in `ggplot2`. Suppose I want to create a scatterplot from iris dataset:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width, colour=Species)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: Iris scatterplot]

But suppose I don't like `ggplot2` default theme and palette. Let's say I want to use `theme_bw` and `Dark2` palette:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width, colour=Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2")
```

[image: Iris scatterplot with another colour palette]

And suppose I have lots of plots and I want all of them using `theme_bw` and `Dark2` palette. I know I can use `theme_set(theme_bw())` to make all my plots have the black and white theme. Is there a similar function to make all my plots use `Dark2` palette? In other words, how can I run a code like

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width, colour=Species)) +
  geom_point()
```

and have `theme_bw` and `Dark2` palette in all my plots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be to write a custom wrapper:

```
ggcust <- function(...){
  ggplot(...) +
    theme_bw()
}
```

fill in all the `theme` options you need, then use it like this:

```
ggcust(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Since I wanted both theme and palette, I had to add a line with `scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2")` in your suggested code, but it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you can fill in anything you need within the wrapper, I just wanted to keep the example simple. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 4):

You can also put layers into a `list`:

```r
gglayer_theme <- list(
  theme_bw(),
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2")
)
```

And treat the list like a new layer (Note `+` becomes `,` in this list notation):

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width, colour=Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  gglayer_theme
```

The advantage to the custom wrapper approach is the ability to easily mix layers:

```r
gglayer_labs <- list( 
  labs(
    x = "x",
    y = "y"
  )
)

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width, colour=Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  gglayer_theme +
  gglayer_labs
```

Or combine them beforehand:

```r
gglayer_all <- c(gglayer_theme, gglayer_labs)

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width, colour=Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  gglayer_all
```